# Using list of URLs to extract the data

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, request

I am struggling using list of urls to extract the data. I tried to use this code to fetch data from one url:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.horizont.net/marketing/nachrichten/anzeige.-digitalisierung-wie-software-die-kreativitaet-steigert-178413')
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

and then simply defined what i need from the page:

```
    all = soup.select('.PageArticle')  
    title = []
    author = []
    publish_date = []
    article_main_content = []
    article_body = []
    for item in all:
        t = item.find_all('h1')[0].text
        title.append(t)
        a = item.find_all('span')[2].text
        author.append(a)
        p = item.find_all('span')[5].text
        publish_date.append(p)
        amc = item.select('.PageArticle_lead-content')[0].text
        article_main_content.append(amc)
        a_body = item.select('.PageArticle_body')[0].text
        article_body.append(a_body)
```

Now i have list of URLS and want to get same results but by list of URLs... Any idea how?  At the moment i am getting this output:

```
Schweizer Illustrierte und L'illustré rücken näher zusammen 
Beat Hürlimann
11. November 2019
```

But i need same results for all urls "article name", "Author" and "Publish date"

Comment: "Now i have list of URLS and want to get same results but by list of URLs... Any idea how? " Its not the same?? post current output and desired output

Comment: I am getting reult for only for 1 URL  r = `requests.get('https://www.horizont.net/marketing/nachrichten/anzeige.-digitalisierung-wie-software-die-kreativitaet-steigert-178413')` but i have list urls from which i want to fetch same things as i mentioned in my code.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate list?? for url in urls:    request.get(url) ...

Comment: Thanks. I finally able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling. I able to find the solution.

```
 for url in url_list:
        r = requests.get(url)
        c = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
        all = soup.select('.PageArticle')

    for item in all:

            t = item.find_all('h1')[i].text
            title.append(t)
            print(t)
            a = item.find_all('span')[j].text
            author.append(a)
            print(a)
            p = item.find_all('span')[k].text
            publish_date.append(p)
            print(p)


i = i +1 
j += 1
k += 1
l += 1
```